# Django Queryset crash when string in integerfields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a search screen where the parameters are entered and filtered using a queryset.

I have an integerfield and if the user enters in alpha characters in it, it will crash when I perform a queryset.filter because there's alpha in an integer.

Is there a way to get django to simply discard this rather than raising an exception?

Thank you.

Comment: why not check cases like alpha characters before passing it to django query set filter call

Comment: What do you mean with "crash"? Can you provide views and models?

Comment: catch the exception?

Comment: Use a `try`-`except`. But perhaps there is a more elegant way. Can you share your (relevant) views/urls/...

Comment: By 'crash' I meant raise an exception. Yes, I can do a try/except but I was hoping there would be a way to return a blank queryset... Perhaps I should do a queryset.none() if I raise an exception...

I was hoping there was something I could pass into a queryset to prevent such a failure.

As for not catching before the queryset call. Some of these screens have a ton of different fields passed in and there is a template which can pass them dynamically, so it would be a pain to check for every single one.

Comment: I think the easy solution is to do try/except and return an empty queryset.

Answer (score 1):

You should validate user input via form before handing it to model. 
[IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) would help you.